# Shrink massive areas of terrain down to for nether hub

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So for my SMP server we are going to do a scale down version of the overworld in **3D** for our nether hub. Its going to be a replica of our world but 1/8 the scale of it. I don't need any trees or structures but just the basic terrain. I've tried build //scale in builders utility but its to much of a monumental task to compute. Is there any mapping programs/custom world generators that can generate a world at 1/8 of the original scale or that can just shrink down massive areas of terrain.

Im using 1.15.2 and the seed to my world is 5824646491735756214

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Gnembon's recent Scarpet script for [mapping the world in-game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqgyvnjEAn4) would be the best tool to prepare the 'pattern' of the map.

[image]

Obviously you can't use this directly to create the nether hub... or if you can, it would be very troublesome. But what you can do:

- Start a separate server with a copy of your world and [Carpet mod](https://github.com/gnembon/fabric-carpet/releases/tag/v1.4-homebound) version 1.4.
- Install the scarpet [mapping script](https://github.com/gnembon/scarpet/blob/master/programs/survival/world_map.sc)
- Adjust the map scale from default 1:16 to 1:8, and optionally customize the script, e.g. strip the structures generation code or add height to mountains etc.
- Generate the chunks you want in your Nether hub (just fly around to get them generated.)
- Generate the map, as per Gnembon's video.
- Use [Litematica](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/litematica) (client-side mod) to create a schematic file of the map area that is to be your Nether hub.
- On your actual server, in survival, prepare the location of the Nether hub, gather materials as listed with Litematica's 'materials list' for the schematic, and then just build the map, using Litematica to guide you through the process.
- Transform the map into the actual Nether hub. Add portals, possibly add a glass floor above the map, maybe spawn-proof it etc.

Comment: Yeah i was already doing that its just i would like to have the actual terrain as well. Like for example if there's a big mountain i would like that to mirror in the nether. I have started doing your idea before you posted that but thanks. ill guess i have to transform it myself.